# What is the default for pdfs in rmarkdown?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I know it's a trifling question but am finding it difficult to obtain the information. Does anyone know what the default font is on pdfs in rmarkdown? I really like it and would like to use it in word.

Answer (score 1):

the default RStudio markdown PDF output uses the default LaTeX font, Computer Modern. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Modern